# Unable to cast object of type 'System._ComObject to type Windows.UI.xaml.Hosting.IElementCompositionPreviewStatistics

Tags: visual-studio-2015, uwp, windows-10-mobile, uwp-xaml

I get this exception thrown when I try to deploy an application to a mobile device when using the composition api with xaml. The exception is thrown at this code line

```
 var manipulator = ElementCompositionPreview.GetScrollViewerManipulationPropertySet(scrollviewer)
```

The windows 10 sdk is up to date and so is Visual studio

```
EDIT:

Phone OS version : 10.0.10536.1004 (Mobile insider preview)
Windows Software Development Kit : 10.1.10586.212
```

Running the application on my local machine (desktop) it doesn't give this error. It only gives the error when I try to deploy it to mobile.

Comment: Please post the code and the version of Windows SDK and version of Windows you're running the app on.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I updated the post with the os versions. The code that throws the error was already in the post. I don't know if you need more on than just the line that throws the error. If so, I will make another edit

Comment: The versions don't match, so there is no guarantee anything will work properly. You can only reliably use matching OS and SDK versions.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT changed my insider settings and I now have the update to match that of the SDK. Thanks

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT: Is this specific to the Composition API, or is there a general requirement that SDK and device versions must match? Either way, this doesn't sound right. I would be somewhat surprised if I couldn't use the Windows 10 SDK to write Windows 7 applications.

Comment: @IInspectable  I think it is specific to the composition API. The composition Api is unique to Windows 10 AFAIK

Comment: It is unique to Insider Preview SDKs. The OS is still under development so APIs can change or be removed.